# Pegar tempo de acesso à uma página e gravar no BD

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, funções

Preciso pegar o tempo que o usuário ficou em uma determinada página, e ao usuário abandonar a página, este tempo seja registrado no banco de dados.

Alguém teria alguma ideia de como fazer?

[Editado]

O tempo eu consegui pegar usando javascript.
O problema está em registrar este tempo de acesso no banco de dados.
Tentei usar o seguinte código para enviar o tempo de acesso via POST e em seguida capturar e inserir via mysql, porém não funcionou:

```
<form action="post" id="register_access">
    <input type="hidden" value="1" name="access_time" id="access_time"/>        
</form>
<script>
var contador = 0;

setTimeout(temporizador,1000);

function temporizador() {
  if(contador < 10000000){
    setTimeout(temporizador,1000);
  }
  document.getElementById('access_time').value = contador;
  contador++;
}

jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $(window).on('beforeunload', function(e) {
      $('#register_access').submit();
      //return 'Are you sure?';
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: Isto seria feito com javascript

Comment: É um site, ou um sistema?

Comment: No caso seria um site KaduAmaral...

Comment: Porque não usa o [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/)?

Comment: Preciso registrar o tempo de acesso no meu banco de dados. Google Analytics não rola pro que quero fazer KaduAmaral... mesmo assim valeu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiramente (e obviamente) você precisa de uma tabela pra armazenar essas informações:

```
Tabela
 - ID
 - Session
 - Page
 - User
 - DateStart
 - DateEnd
```

Crie uma função para mandar os dados pro servidor:

```
<script>
  function temporizador(time) {
    var dados = {
      page: window.location.pathname
    };

    var posttimeurl = 'http://endereco/para/cadastrar/tempo.php';

    $.ajax({
      url: posttimeurl,
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: json,
      data: dados,
      success: function(json){
        console.log(json);
      },
      error: function(x, s, h){
        console.log(s, x);
      }, 
      complete: function(){
        setTimeout(function(){ temporizador(time); }, time);
      }
    });

  };
  // Inicia o fluxo 
  temporizador(1000); // Tempo enviado no parâmetro
</script>
```

Receba os dados no servidor e cadastre no banco:

```
<?php

  session_start();

  $ret = Array('success' => FALSE, 'msg' => '');

  if (empty($_POST['page'])){
    $ret['msg'] = 'Página inválida';
    exit( json_encode($ret) );
  }

  // Se usuário logado coloque o ID dele, exemplo:
  // $userID = $_SESSION['user']['id'];

  $dados = Array(
    'session' => session_id(),
    'page' => $_POST['page'],
    'user' => '' // ou $userID
  );


  // Ou faça um UPDATE se a sessão já existir
  $sql  = "SELECT id FROM tabela WHERE `session` = '{$dados['session']}' AND `page` = '{$dados['page']}';";
  $id = $res['id'];
  // Insira $dados no banco se a sessão não existir
  $sql  = "INSERT INTO tabela (`session`, `page`, `user`, `datestart`, `dateend`) 
           VALUES ('{$dados['session']}', '{$dados['page']}', '{$dados['user']}', NOW(), NOW());";

  // Se a sessão existir faça um UPDATE
  $sql  = "UPDATE tabela SET `dateend` = NOW() WHERE id = {$id}";

  $ret['success'] = TRUE;
  $ret['msg']     = 'Dados registrados/atualizados';

  exit( json_encode($ret) );
```

Assim você vai ter um log de quanto tempo cada sessão durou em cada página. Você pode ainda armazenar o IP, Browser, Resolução e etc...

Comment: Obviamente a tabela e os comandos mysql eu já tenho amigo Kadu Amaral, só não postei o código inteiro... meu problema é que o código que postei não estava conseguindo enviar os dados via POST.

Vou analisar o código que postou e tentar implementar aqui, ai em seguida posto os resultados.. Valeu!