# Calcular tempo logado - PHP

Tags: php

Alguém sabe como posso calcular o total de tempo que um usuário fica logado no meu site? Considerando que precisa pausar a contagem de tempo quando fechar o navegador.

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/75071/pegar-tempo-de-acesso-%C3%A0-uma-p%C3%A1gina-e-gravar-no-bd

Comment: Não é possivel detectar que o navegador fechou de maneira eficiente, leia estes links pra entender http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/70316/3635 e http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/71023/3635

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salva a data que o usuário entrou no sistema em uma table e a hora que ele sair. No *mysql* use `NOW()` pra trazer a hora atual, se o fuso horário tiver diferente use `DATE_ADD( NOW( ) , INTERVAL +3 HOUR )`. E vá ajustando as horas conforme seu servidor.

Quanto a questão dele fechar o navegador eu uso outros recursos como a cada 5min verifico se ele esta on line se não registro a saída.

Comment: Eu uso dois métodos:

1. cada pagina que ele acessa atualiza a hora na tabela, rodo uma  tarefa cron a cada 10min e comparo o ultimo acesso com a hora atual se for maior que 10min removo ele.
2. faco mesmo esquema so que na session a cada atualizacao de pagina a session adiciona 10min se passar disso e ele for atualizar destruo a session e direciono pra login.

caso queira a funcao de comparar tempo eu tenho :)

Comment: Como tu aconselha verificar se está online? Javascript, crontab, ou com o que?
Pelo que vi, com javascript parece mais fácil, mas talvez não é o mais aconselhado, principalmente por poder ser bloqueado no navegador.

Comment: no meu sistema eu coloco um status na tabela do banco quando o usuário entra no sistema, tipo 0 offline e 1 online ai só alterar quando ele efetuar login ou logout. e como falei anteriormente executo uma função por x tempo pra ver se ele atualizou por um período a pagina ou passou pra outra.

Answer (score 3):

Meu Sistema pra verifica usuario logado

Coloco no include header esse jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function insereLog()
        {
            $.ajax({
                url: "funcoes.php?acao=log"
            });
        }
         setInterval(function(){ insereLog(); }, 60000); // a cada minuto ele dispara essa funcão e manda um post naquele arquivo funcoes.php
 </script>
```

No arquivo funcoes.php

```
<?php
include("conexao_banco.php");//arquivo conexão ao banco
include("res_trito.php"); // arquivo que verifica se o usuário acesso a paginas session etc
if($_GET["acao"] == "log") //post recebido da  funcao inserelog do jquery
{
session_start();
mysql_query("UPDATE usuarios_sistema SET ultimo_acesso = DATE_ADD( NOW()) Where usuario = '$_SESSION[usuario que esta logado]' ");
}
?>
```

Ai vc cria uma tabela no banco com os campos exemplos que citei assim:

usuários_sistema,status_online( 0 ou 1 onde 0 e off e 1 online) ou o que vc escolher e um campo ultimo_acesso pra atualizar a hora a cada 60 segundos e vai atualizar com o nome do usuário que esta na session.

E por ultimo vc cria um arquivo que verifica os usuários online de tempos em tempos

verfificar_usuarios.php

```
$inicio = substr($logout,11); // vc faz um select no banco antes disso e guarda a ultima hora acessada nessa variável $logout. Caso tenha mais de um usuário(claro que vai ter né :) ) vc faz um while e coloca isso tudo dentro do while pra ele verificar vários usuários.
$fim = new DateTime();
$inicio = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i:s', $inicio);
$intervalo = $inicio->diff($fim);
$diferenca = $intervalo->format('%H:%I:%S');

 if ($diferenca > '00:10:00') {//vc define o intervalo para remover o usuario online
     //Se tiver mais de 10 minutos sem acesso vc faz uma ação como update tirando status de 1 para 0 na sua tabela de usuários 
 }
```

Esse arquivo coloco em uma tarefa cron pra rodar de tempos em tempos ai vc defini sua prioridade. Se gostou curte a resposta ai :)